# How to get a row that has the maximum value in a column?

Tags: mysql

How to get a row that has the maximum value in a column?

This below works for me but I don't know if there is another cleaner way..

```
SELECT * FROM `moto` where (matricula = (SELECT max(matricula) FROM `moto`))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this is the way to go. Mind you, this will get you *all* the rows with that max, if there are multiple

(This query is also featured in one of my MySQL book (o'reilly). It's sort of a classic example)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `SELECT * FROM moto ORDER BY matricula DESC LIMIT 1`