# Sqlite sorted rows within group by

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables user and log. I would like to join the user table with logs and get the latest log entry. I have noted that using the group by the rows inside the group are not sorted. Therefore I am not able to retrieve the latest log row.

USER:

```
 ID    |   Name
--------------------
  1    |   John    
  2    |   Mike
```

LOG:

```
L_ID | ACTION  | DATE     | USERID
----------------------------------
1    | OPEN    | '1 DEC'  |   1
2    | CLOSE   | '3 DEC'  |   1
3    | WRITE   | '2 DEC'  |   1
4    | OPEN    | '5 DEC'  |   2
5    | CLOSE   | '3 DEC'  |   2
```

With this table the result I would like to have is:

```
2 Mike 4 OPEN  '5 DEC'
1 Jhon 2 CLOSE '3 DEC'
```

I know that the following query is not working since rows inside the group are not sorted:

```
Select * from user join log on ID=USERID group by ID order by DATE DESC,L_ID
```

Also the following is not working since only the correct date is returned but not the actions:

```
Select ID,Name,Action,Max(Date) from user join log on ID=USERID group by ID order by DATE DESC, L_ID
```

Any idea suggestion how to write the query that will return the correct result?

Comment: what will be the result if two action for userid 1 has same date?

Comment: @hkutluay you are right table log also has an ID after date, ID is used for sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT u.*, l.* 
FROM user AS u 
INNER JOIN log AS l ON l.USERID=u.ID 
WHERE l.DATE = (SELECT max(DATE) FROM log WHERE l.USERID=u.ID ORDER BY L_ID DESC LIMIT 1)

2 Mike 4 OPEN  '5 DEC'
1 Jhon 2 CLOSE '3 DEC'
```

This should work in MySQL, hence sqlite too hopefully.. This may not be the best optimized, I hope to see someone more knowledgeable giving the exact query.

This supposes your date field is proper date time field and not strings. These [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842729/how-do-i-select-populate-two-objects-from-two-tables-with-a-single-query) [might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641384/how-to-get-a-row-that-has-the-maximum-value-in-a-column) give you some more idea.

Please also note that ordering by ID is not safe, it need not be always first record, lesser id.. it depends. So always have a safe second sort column, something like weight or so which stands for 'time' or your own custom rank.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively I also found a solution to the problem but probably my solution is "risky" as it relies on a non documented assumption. I noted that group by takes the latest row of the group as the reference row. So what I did is to split the query in 2 and make sure the row I want to be referenced by group by is the latest one of the first query:

```
Select * from (
               Select * from user join log on ID=USERID order by DATE,L_ID
              )
        group by ID order by DATE DESC
```